# Access session in user model .save()

Tags: django, session

Is it possible to access the current session in the user model .save()?

pseudo code of what I want to achieve:

```
# users.models.py
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    created = True
    if self.pk:
        created = False

    super(AbstractUser, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    # post-save

    if created:
         look_for_invite_in_session_and_register_if_found(self, session)
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems it something wrong in your architecture. You shouldn't access request in models layer. All work with request must be done in view. You can do it like this:

```
user, created = AbstractUser.objects.get_or_create(name=name)
if created:
    look_for_invite_in_session_and_register_if_found(user, request.session)
```

Comment: I'm using all-auth for authentication, so i do not have full controll over the create user flow. I'm currently looking in to building a middleware connecting user with invites.